# DynamoDb - Filter or Scan based on attributes in Collection of DynamoDBDocument

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to know if it is possible to filter / scan based on attributes in a collection of DynamoDBDocuments.  Lets say I have this:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Orders")
public class Order {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime orderDate;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Address shipTo;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Address billTo;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private List<OrderItem> items;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class Address {
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class OrderItem {
    private String product;
    private int qty;
    private double itemCost;
}
```

Lets assume I want to find all orders which have one or more items where the product is "widgets".  I believe the answer is no.  With a relational DB I would do:
SELECT o FROM Orders o, OrderItems i WHERE o.id = i.id AND i.product="widgets"

Would a better practice be to put the order items in their own table and have a orderId attribute in it and then query order items based on the product and then grab the order based on the order ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a map instead of a list for `@DynamoDBAttribute items`, where the key of the map is the `product`, then you can use a filter expression `attribute_exists(items.widgets)` to down-select.